# I can't seem to understand how to get the XYZ position of the city I'm looking for

Tags: here-api

I'm currently trying out the HERE API to see if it would fit my needs.
For that, I'm trying to get access to the flow datas but I get confronted to the following problem :
For this REST entrypoint, HERE is asking me to input the position of the city I'm looking for in X/Y/Z.

If I read the right informations, those are related to the tiles but even though, I can't seem to find any place where I can input a city and it would give me a X/Y/Z output...

If I'm totally wrong about the informations and missed the point here, I'm very sorry about the time you lost reading this question.

But if you have any tip for me, thank you very much in advance !
Have a great day.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve and add examples of what you tried? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you please provide the details of the API that you have faced problem with. A little more about the use case ?

Comment: At the moment, i would like to get the traffic flow data of Geneva Switzerland.
I would like to use those data to asses the quality of the data gathered by our own means.

As Here Developer Support suggested, I tried to understand the Mercator Projection but as I am not really into geomatics, I must say that I struggle to understand it :(

Answer (score 1):

To request traffic flow data for a location, you may use any of these addressing schemes: `[z]/[x]/[y]`, **Quadkey**, **Bounding box**, **Proximity** or **Corridor**. See the traffic API documentation to see how you can generate the `[z]/[x]/[y]` via the Mercator Projection:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics_v6.1/example-flow-intro.html

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for this quick reply !
I will investigate the links you gave me and the "Mercator Projection" !